# delete all folders with tmp in name using batch file

Tags: windows, batch, directory, tmp

Have tried to google this, but I always seem to get results relating to .tmp files, which isnt really any use.

I have only a basic understanding of batch files, but I think I need something like this:

```
rmdir "D:\*.tmp"
```

Windows update seems to be dumping all of it's .tmp folders onto our D drive, as it has the most free space. Fine, but it doesnt then delete them afterwards.

I'm looking to write a batch file, that will go through and delete any folder that has .tmp at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw this one liner into a bat file:

`FOR /D /R c:\FOLDERLOCATION %%X IN (*.tmp) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"`

- /D - For Directory
- /R - Recursive

This will remove the folders ending in tmp and anything under it. If you want to get fancy you can run it like this:

```
@echo off
set dir="c:\FOLDERLOCATION\"
FOR /D /R %dir% %%X IN (*.tmp) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
pause
exit
```

Comment: You absolute Gem! Does the job perfectly, thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `/S` to the end of that line, I believe it will delete all specified folders and sub-folders that match your wildcard search.  If you can confirm that it works, then you can throw it into Notepad and save it as a `.bat` file.  Unfortunately, I'm old school and don't know how to do it the Powershell way.  :o(

Comment: well I looked for the powershell equivelent, which appears to be "Remove-Item C:\Test* -recurse". If I can not find a batch version to do the same, I will just install powershell on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've improved @RomeNYRR's answer - thanks @RomeNYRR!

The command now echoes deleted folders and hides "element not found" error messages:

```
for /d /r . %X in (*.tmp) do @rmdir /s /q "%X" 2> nul && @echo Deleted %X
```

Great if you need to clean after your compiler... ;)

```
for /d /r . %X in (bin obj) do @rmdir /s /q "%X" 2> nul && @echo Deleted %X
```