# Delete all folders on all drives with "foo" OR "bar" in the folder name with batchfile

Tags: batch-file, ms-dos, windows-batch

I am trying to **delete all folders on all drives with the above naming pattern**, however only on the first folder level, i.e directly below the drive letter, like for example:

```
F:\this folder's name contains FOO and should be deleted
```

...without confirmation nor error message (e.g. in case no folders are found), with a batchfile.

I've found this:
[delete all folders with tmp in name using batch file](https://serverfault.com/questions/384885/delete-all-folders-with-tmp-in-name-using-batch-file) and am wondering if the solution from there is a good starting point?

```
@echo off
set dir="c:\FOLDERLOCATION\"
FOR /D /R %dir% %%X IN (*.tmp) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Read and follow [`FOR` - Conditionally perform a command several times.](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html). You could apply either [FOR-Folders](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), or [FOR-Command Results](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) as follows:

**FOR-Folders** (disadvantages: case insensitive; wildcards allow no regex-like pattern so we need to run a loop more times).

```
@echo off
set "dir=c:\FOLDERLOCATION\"
pushd "%dir%"
::                          ↓↓↓↓                      echo for debugging
FOR /D /R %%X IN (*foo*) DO echo RMDIR /S /Q "%%~fX"
FOR /D /R %%X IN (*bar*) DO echo RMDIR /S /Q "%%~fX"
::                          ↑↑↑↑                      echo for debugging
popd
pause
```

**FOR-Command Results** in combination with [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (advantages: `findstr` independently allows both case sensitive and regex-like search pattern):

```
@echo off
set "dir=c:\FOLDERLOCATION\"
FOR /F "delims=" %%X IN ('dir /B/S /A:D "%dir%" ^| findstr /I "foo|bar"') DO 2>NUL echo RMDIR /S /Q "%%~fX"
:: ECHO in above line merely for debugging
pause
```

A disadvantage is that `dir` list is generated statically so we need to [redirect error messages using `2>NUL`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Awesome! Would it be also possible to leave the batchfile running invisibly and wait for new drives to appear, like external hard drives etc., and then act on these as well?

Comment: Btw., what does set "dir=c:\FOLDERLOCATION\" do?

Comment: [Dealing with quotes in Windows batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535975/). Define a variable as  `set "dir=c:\FOLDERLOCATION\"` (its value does not include double quotes) and use it quoted if necessary e.g. `type "%dir%%file%%ext%"` (providing  `set "file=some file name"` and `set "ext=.ext"`)